# Validating a choice javascript

Tags: javascript

I need some help i know its a pretty simple solution but i keep getting stuck on this part of the code i need to validate my choice of 1, 2 or 3 and go to that website Thanks in advance

To some it up i need the user to either chose 1 2 or 3, user select 1 2 or 3 will prompt them to enter a height and width of 500 if eneterted below output error if entered correctly go to that site just need it to validate the choice

```js
function redirect() {
  
  var choice=0;
 var height;
 var width;
 var url = Number (prompt("Pick a site? 1. xxxx 2. xxxx 3. xxx", ""));
    switch (url)
 
    
 {    
 case 1:
   
   while(!isFinite(height) || height < 500) {
      height = prompt("Enter a height > 500"); 
   }
     
   while(!isFinite(width) || width < 500) {
      width = prompt("Enter a width > 500");
   }
  window.open(url="http://www.xxx", "myWindow","status = 1, height = 500, width = 500, resizable = 0");   
  break;
   
 case 2:
   
   while(!isFinite(height) || height < 500) {
      height = prompt("Enter a height > 500");
   }
     
   while(!isFinite(width) || width < 500) {
      width = prompt("Enter a width > 500");
   }
  window.open(url="http://xxx", "myWindow","status = 1, height = 500, width = 500, resizable = 0");
  break;
    
 case 3:
   
   while(!isFinite(height) || height < 500) {
      height = prompt("Enter a height > 500");
   }
     
   while(!isFinite(width) || width < 500) {
      width = prompt("Enter a width > 500");
   }
  
  window.open(url="http://www.xxx", "myWindow","status = 1, height = 500, width = 500, resizable = 0");
  break;
  
  default:
  alert("Please enter number 1, 2, or 3 to select a website"); 
  return false;  
  }// end switch
 
  return;
}
```

```
<button type="button" onclick="redirect()" onsubmit="return validateForm()">Go to other websites</button>
```

Comment: explain what doesn't work and what is expected to happen

Comment: sorry about that Use a switch statement to set the chosen url and validate the user choice, do not continue until you have a valid choice. Everything works just need to validate that's all

Comment: Can you turn it into a snippet? Click the `<>` button. Will be easier to find what's wrong, since you have some functions that aren't included as well, namely `isFinite`. From a glance, you're doing that already with the `while` loops. So I don't really see what's not working (especially without a working example).

Comment: This is the code that is on a form I had to create to enter credit card details and submit  on this  form there is a button called go to other websites this is the part I have to focus on and validate once the user has chosen option 1 2 or 3 it needs to validate that selected option

Answer (score 0):

You've already had a while loop, so I don't why you didn't just use a similar logic to check.

```
var url;

while (url === undefined || [1,2,3].indexOf(url) === -1)
{
  url = prompt("Pick a site? 1. xxxx 2. xxxx 3. xxx", "");
  if (url === null)
  {
    return false;
  }
  url = Number(url);
}
```

the `url === null` with `return` is to allow your users to actually exit the infinite prompt loop if they decide to cancel or w/e. You should use this for your width/height as well (though that's up to you).

Snippet below:

```js
function redirect() {
  
  var choice=0;
 var height;
 var width;
  var url;
 
  let i = 0;
  while (url === undefined || [1,2,3].indexOf(url) === -1)
  {
    url = prompt("Pick a site? 1. xxxx 2. xxxx 3. xxx", "");
    if (url === null)
    {
      return false;
    }
    url = Number(url);
  }
    
  switch (url)   
 {    
 case 1:
   
   while(!isFinite(height) || height < 500) {
      height = prompt("Enter a height > 500"); 
   }
     
   while(!isFinite(width) || width < 500) {
      width = prompt("Enter a width > 500");
   }
  window.open(url="http://www.xxx", "myWindow","status = 1, height = 500, width = 500, resizable = 0");   
  break;
   
 case 2:
   
   while(!isFinite(height) || height < 500) {
      height = prompt("Enter a height > 500");
   }
     
   while(!isFinite(width) || width < 500) {
      width = prompt("Enter a width > 500");
   }
  window.open(url="http://xxx", "myWindow","status = 1, height = 500, width = 500, resizable = 0");
  break;
    
 case 3:
   
   while(!isFinite(height) || height < 500) {
      height = prompt("Enter a height > 500");
   }
     
   while(!isFinite(width) || width < 500) {
      width = prompt("Enter a width > 500");
   }
  
  window.open(url="http://www.xxx", "myWindow","status = 1, height = 500, width = 500, resizable = 0");
  break;
  
  default:
  break;
  }// end switch
 
  return;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="redirect()" onsubmit="return validateForm()">Go to other websites</button>
```